# Complex Conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of numbers. I want to be able to highlight a cell in another column if, there are three numbers in three consecutive cells in the column greater than zero and the three numbers add up to less than 71. If there are only one or two numbers in three consecutive cells greater than zero nothing should happen. I know how to set up the conditional formatting to highlight the cell in another column, what I don't know how to do is construct a formula that will look at the numbers in the column and pick out 3 consecutive non-zeros that add up to less than 71 (or if that can be done at all).

[image: Example Excel Sheet]

Comment: As this isn't directly related to programming, I've flagged it as off-topic. http://superuser.com/ would be a better place to ask this :)

Answer (score 0):

The conditional formatting formula would be

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B1:B3,">0")=3,SUM(B1:B3)<71)
```

applied to cells A1:A28 in the data above. The only cell which fits the criteria and should be highlighted is cell A9.

Because of relative addressing the formula always looks in the three cells in column B starting with the current row, e.g. for row 9 the formula is effectively

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B9:B11,">0")=3,SUM(B9:B11)<71)
```